# What is a more personal email address than support@yourdomain.com or sales@yourdomain.com for a Service-oriented product?

Tags: email, customer-support

If you have an email where you want your users to contact you with any and all questions, a true concierge/high-touch point of contact, what would you call it?

Most products use emails like:

- support@yourdomain.com
- sales@yourdomain.com
- team@yourdomain.com

This falls in line with not calling your Twitter 'Support' handle anything to do with support i.e. @AskAmex instead of @AmexSupport.

What is a suitable handle to be using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you have an email where you want your users to contact you with any and all questions, a true concierge/high-touch point of contact, what would you call it?

I'd probably just call it support@yourdomain.com. It's clear and obvious.

I wouldn't worry about anything sneakier because the reputation and impression for a true concierge/high-touch point of contact will not come from the email address. It will come from:

- how the contact is framed on the site
- customers' previous experience of customer support
- the reputation of the company for customer support.

To pick an example - rackspace has a fantastic reputation in the dev community for *fanatically* good support. Look at their support page. http://www.rackspace.com/support/ what it does is make it *really easy to get support*. It shows individuals in the banner to emphasise that you're getting humans not an inbox. They're emphasising the more personal and immediate contact methods over the less-immediate / less-expensive ones. Phone calls first. Then live chat. Then links to direct support help. You go to pages that users might visit with problems (e.g. their status page http://status.apps.rackspace.com/) and you see those sorts of links again.

Forget about the email address. Make it simple and understandable and useful. Place it in a context where the design is demonstrating to the users that support is valued and done well. And make sure that the support actually *is* valued and done well.

That last one is the most important.

Answer (score 3):

Adam,
While I understand why you would want to use an address that is more personal to the user but in this case I would ask why? What is it that your trying to give to the user then what they directly need? Users have become accustom to the addresses above and know contextually what that address will do for them. If you had something like askanne@yourdomain.com. It could work but the user will wonder who is Anne and why is she answering my question? I would also ask what's the business value? How are you trying to change the perception of the brands value to the user just by giving them something they don't really know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

How about John.Smith@yourdomain.com? What's more personal than the name of the support guy? Or the name of the team leader if it's a bunch of guys. Any problems resulting from personnel change can be easily dealt with behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

**hello@yourdomain.com**

It's both friendly and general, and gives the impression that there is a human on the other side.

Comment: Yeah, but it makes me wonder whether am I putting a support question to a sales person or the other way round. Unless I have previous experience with the site operator, I'd start looking for a more specific e-mail address.

Comment: @MarjanVenema The question was for a more personal email to cover a wider range of topics.  Of course if you want one jusp for sales or just for support, use support@ and sales@.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest simply

```
contact@yourdomain.com
```

it can be a single address for a list of many address or there is some solution who permit to fetch the content, subject or other rules and redirect to the needed departement

Example: subject contain 'need support', the email will be redirected or forwarded to support@yourdomain.com